# Determine whether the subset is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

So what I want to do is determine whether the following subsets are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

$$\{(x,y)\mid x+y=0 \}$$
$$\{(x,y)\mid x+y=1\}$$
$$\mathbb{Q^2}$$

And I really have no idea where to start. I know that it needs to satisfy closure under addition, and that my set needs to contain the $\textbf{0}$ and that it needs to be closed under scalar multiplication, but I don't know how to properly apply these statements. If someone could give me a push in the right direction, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: does the second one contain $\mathbf 0$?  what could happen if you multiply an element of the third one by a scalar (assuming it's in $\mathbb R$)?

Comment: By the looks of it, no. Since it states all $x,y$ such that $x+y=1$. My biggest problem is interpreting the way the sets are written and translating them into something meaningful.

Comment: Is $\mathbf Q^2$ stable by scalar multiplication for any real number?

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp:  You are correct about the second one, so it's not a subspace (it's an affine line)

Comment: Note that knowing what is the field of scalars is important. $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be a vector space with $\mathbb{R}$ as the scalar, but it could also be a vector space with $\mathbb{Q}$ as the field of scalars. In the first case $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is not a subspace, but in the second it is.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Does that also mean that the first one is a subspace? By the looks of it, it contains $\textbf{0}$, and is closed under both scalar multiplication and addition.

Comment: @Bernard I am thinking if I let $c$ be some arbitrary irrational scalar, then $c$ multiplied by some arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{Q^2}$, $c\vec{u} \notin \mathbb{Q^2}$ which would mean no. Is that right?

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp Right on both counts: first one is a subspace, third one is not.

Comment: You said "my biggest problem is interpreting the way the sets are written and translating them into something meaningful," but I don't understand what you mean.  You read the second definition and figured out that it's the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $x + y = 1$; in what way is this description not "meaningful"?

Comment: It is perfectly right – $π(0,1)=(0,π)\notin\mathbf Q^2$, for instance.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Not meaningful is definitely me wording it the wrong way, it's just that I have a hard time making sense of what it actually means for it to be a set of all $(x,y)$ such that $x+y=1$. I'm fairly new to linear algebra in general and I'm kind of slow on the pick up since it's just so different to everything I've done in mathematics so far, that being mostly calculus/multivar and its kind.

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp If you prefer, "the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $x + y = 1$" is the same as "the line $y = 1-x$".  Does that help?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, thank you, that is a much more intuitive version of reading it for a beginner like myself. I need to properly make myself acquainted with method of reading things.